# How to sum() a column in alasql (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel-2010, alasql

I have the following output table:

```
Quote | art0001 | art0002 | art0003 |
=====================================
100   |    4    |    1    |    5    |
99    |    0    |   10    |    1    |
98    |   12    |    5    |   19    |
97    |    1    |    0    |    6    |
96    |    0    |    1    |    0    |
...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |
```

Well, I need the sum of the columns of `art000x` to expand the output table with the total amount of the individual articles:

```
=====================================
      |   17    |   17    |   31    |
```

Currently the `alasql`-Code is defined as below:

```
var sqlRequest = [
        'SELECT Quote, \ ' +
        'art0001, \ ' +
        'art0002, \ ' +
        'art0003, \ ' +
        'art0004, \ ' +
        'art0005, \ ' +
        'art0006, \ ' +
        'art0007, \ ' +
        'art0008, \ ' +
        'art0009, \ ' +
        'art0010, \ ' +
        'art0011, \ ' +
        'art0012, \ ' +
        'art0013, \ ' +
        'art0014 \ ' +
        'INTO XLSXML("Test.xls", ?) FROM ?'
    ];

var opts = {
   headers: true
}

$scope.btnExport = function () {
   alasql(sqlString[0], [opts, $scope.listOfItems]);
}
```

An additional question: How can I reduce the sql SELECT string?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- No reason to add your `\`
- When getting the SUM of each `art0xx` select `SUM(art0xx)`.
- When summing up it does not make sense to also get the `Quote` field -

So I suggest you use:

```
'SELECT 'SUM(art0001) as art0001, ' +
    'SUM(art0002) as art0002, ' +
    'SUM(art0003) as art0003, ' +
    'SUM(art0004) as art0004, ' +
    'SUM(art0005) as art0005, ' +
    'SUM(art0006) as art0006, ' +
    'SUM(art0007) as art0007, ' +
    'SUM(art0008) as art0008, ' +
    'SUM(art0009) as art0009, ' +
    'SUM(art0010) as art0010, ' +
    'SUM(art0011) as art0011, ' +
    'SUM(art0012) as art0012, ' +
    'SUM(art0013) as art0013, ' +
    'SUM(art0014) as art0014, ' +
    'INTO XLSXML("Test.xls", ?) FROM ?'
```

Comment: You don't understand my problem. My code exports the json data in an excel file. In this excel are the columns of article numbers and their indication of quantities. After these output data I need to add the total quantity of each column.

Comment: You cant add data to an existing Excel file - only rewrite all of it. The above code will give you the output you requested.

Comment: How can I add data to an existing Excel file? When I use your proposal then the program create a file `Test(1).xls`

Comment: You cant add data to existing excel file with AlaSQL. Have a look at https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx